# Counting Subgraph Instances

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, np-complete, isomorphism

Let's say I have a large (several thousand node) directed graph *G* and a much smaller (3-5 node) directed graph *g*.  I want to count how many isomorphisms of *g* are in *G*.  In other words, I want to know how many unique sets of nodes in *G* match *g*.  I realize that this is an instance of the subgraph isomorphism problem and is therefore NP-complete.  However, given that you may assume that *g* is small, is there any reasonably efficient algorithm for doing this?

Comment: Maybe the http://math.stackexchange.com/ would give you better results - I know what you seek is an algorithm, but you could probably devise an algorithm from theory

Comment: Is your problem "one case" or you want a general algorithm. I ask just because some feature on the cardinality of the edges of g may help a lot ...

Comment: If the size of your smaller graph doesn't grow as a function of N, then even a brute force algorithm should be polynomial time, because N choose k is O(N^k).

Comment: @mcbeckish:  I thought of the O(N^k) algorithm, and that probably won't cut it.

Comment: Yes, even polynomial-time algorithms can take too long.  I just wanted to clarify that if the size of the smaller graph is fixed, then this is not NP-Complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although graph isomorphism is NP-complete in general, problems you come across in the real world are often pretty easy.  A simple brute-force should suffice: Let `M_i` be a set of maps from the first i nodes of g to nodes of G.  Start with `m_0` containing the empty map and extend it one node at a time, discarding any maps which violate the constraint `x->y` iff `m(x)->m(y)`.

You'll want to order the nodes in g so that lots of pruning happens early.  Assuming your graphs are pretty sparse, you'll want an order that completes as many edges as early as possible, maybe a dfs from the highest degree node.

Comment: I thought of this before, but I thought there might be a more clever solution.  Turns out this only takes a few seconds to run for the problem sizes I'm working with.  I guess the lesson is to avoid overcomplicating things.